# how to slice last non-zero row elements from matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix and would like to get the last non-negative element. I happen to already have these indices in an array b

```
 a= [[3, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [24,5, 6, 7, 7, 78, 0, 0, 0],
    [4, 56, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [23, 5, 7, 11, 12, 52, 65, 54, 0]]

 b = [2, 0, 5, 1, 7]
```

Is there an elegant way to extra the last non-zero elements?

```
 c = [1, 6, 78, 56, 54] from a?
```

A loop works, but is not very pythonic.

Comment: Will they always end in a series of `0`?, or is this possible `[1,2,0,0,3,0,0]`

Comment: yes, but that is not so important as I know the index of the element of each row I want anyway.

Comment: With `b` given, use indexing - `np.take_along_axis(a,b[:,None],axis=1).ravel()`.

Comment: This one is the fastest, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions and [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) built-in function:

`[a[i][j] for i, j in enumerate(b)]`

> `[1, 6, 78, 56, 54]`

Answer (score 1):

Something more pythonic might be:

```
a= [[3, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [24,5, 6, 7, 7, 78, 0, 0, 0],
    [4, 56, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [23, 5, 7, 11, 12, 52, 65, 54, 0]]

c = [next(a_element for a_element in  sublist[::-1] if a_element>0) for sublist in a ]
```

However, this will raise a `StopIteration` exception if no `a_element` is `>0`

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the (better) answer by @vurmux, you can also [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
res = [sub[i] for i, sub in zip(b, a)]
print(res)  # -> [1, 6, 78, 56, 54]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility I found:

```
a[range(len(b)), b]
```